# Removing BIOS Post Messages

Tags: motherboard, bios

I am working on a project where a standard x86 desktop system will boot and run a single program until it is shut down. I would like to remove all the bios post messages so that it looks a little more "finished" and cleaner when it starts up.

I was hoping that there might by a standard implementation/terms to know about so I can avoid having to dig through every manual to see if there are options, or get some advice on a standard set of tools I should be using. I was thinking about getting a board that has an image that covers up the post messages until you press a key and trying to customize it to all black, but it's not clear if this is a good direction. I started looking for OEM motherboards but my searches were filled with standard commercial stuff, or seemed to be way to big for my toy project.

What is the best way to go about removing all the bios post messages and just having a blank screen or "loading" message until OS loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a BIOS setting that displays a logo graphic instead of post messages along with some way to use a custom logo graphic. Each manufacturer tends to call this feature something different and have a different way to set it, for example ASUS calls it on newer motherboards "ASUS MyLogo 2" and uses the ASUS Update utility (used to flash a new BIOS to which you can swap in a new logo to replace the existing manufacturer logo).